# Laravel HasManyThrough Same Model with Different Scope

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently running into an issue which has me rethinking if I am approaching the right way. For the sake of the example, I have limited wiggle room in terms of re-architecting but hear me out.

I have two Models which reference the same table, different types of "Users".

Provider:

```
class Provider extends User
{

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('user_type', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('type', '=', 'provider')->orWhere('type', '=', 'admin');
        });

    }

}
```

User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   ...normal user items
}
```

This might sound confusing but a Provider can "own" any number of Users via a "provider_id" column. A Provider can also own another Provider via provider_id. I'm looking to create a relationship in which a "parent" Provider (one who owns another provider) can access the "child" provider's owned users.

I am attempting to use hasManyThrough but keep running into the following error:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias
```

My relationship looks like this:

```
class Provider extends User
{

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('user_type', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('type', '=', 'provider')->orWhere('type', '=', 'admin');
        });

    }

    public function childSavers() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Provider::class, 'provider_id', 'provider_id', 'id', 'id');
    }
}
```

From what I know, it's because I'm attempting to pivot on the same table, but how else would one define this relationship?

Thanks!

Comment: So Provider and User are on the same table and there are no foreign keys right?

Comment: Correct - there is a column in the users table called provider_id which would be used to associate all of this.